# how can I add Scroll View on sprites in 2 D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I want to make ScrolView but it's not working in sprites 2d mode I have to use the image and then my sprites hide behind that image

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Can you please add more info? You can make scroll view of images also. No need for specifically of sprites. Then there is option of RawImages. Technically you can also make scrollview with child as sprites of Gameobjects. You might want to add some snapshots and more details and update your question. That would be more helpful as other community members will also be able to assist you in this.

Comment: I want to Make Scroll View when I put images it works fine but with that size increases so I want to make it on sprites but that doesn't work. Can I use and images together ?? I did that but my sprites hide behind images

Answer (score 0):

[These are images in Container and Scroll View is working fine[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2C9X.png)